# Reorder parent/child rows mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, nested

I need to re-order via form submission rows in a table with the following structure for a nested page layout

**Columns:** (table name is: sourcedocs3)

```
sort1 | sort2 | type
```

---

```
1 | 1 | parent

1 | 2 | child

2 | 1 | no nesting

3 | 1 | parent

3 | 2 | child

3 | 3 | child

4 | 1 | no nesting
```

I need to be able to re-order (via PHP/Mysql) 3 to 1 without losing basic structure -- 3 becomes 1 and all rows with value of 1 are incremented). Sounded simple but I'm having a hard time keeping the structure intact after shuffling (3|1 should be 1|1, 3|2 should be 1|2 etc)

Comment: Could you give the expected output result ?

Comment: Not sure what you need other than the output I outlined in the 2nd paragraph...all sort1 values of 3* should be 1|1, 1|2 etc and all rows with sort1 value > 1 should be incremented. Sorry if this is still to vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE `why_do_people_never_give_the_table_name` SET sort1 = 999 
WHERE sort1 = 3;

UPDATE `why_do_people_never_give_the_table_name` SET sort1 = sort1 + 1 
WHERE sort1 BETWEEN 1 AND 3
ORDER BY sort1 DESC;

UPDATE `why_do_people_never_give_the_table_name` SET sort1 = 1 
WHERE sort1 = 999;

COMMIT;
```

Note that if you were moving a menu to a later position, e.g. moving 2 to 4, you'd want to order the second update in ASCending order.

Comment: "why_do_people_never_give_the_table_name" - funny :) Will check it out. Thanks for the prompt answer.

Comment: "big up" to Bill - worked like a charm. Thanks again for the tutelage.

Comment: Glad to help.  Thanks for taking my table-name commentary in the lighthearted spirit I intended.  :-)  By the way, it's traditional on Stack Overflow to vote up answers that were helpful, or pick as "accepted answer" the one that you found to be the best help.

Comment: Cheers - I've selected your answer as "Accepted"...am new at Stack so can't 'vote up' until my score goes from 6 to 15. Thanks again - always appreciate humor in an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Bill was spot on - but didn't include the PHP code necessary to perform the operation so here is what I ended up with:

```
    <?php
//if new sort number is less than old sortnum
    if ($newsortnum < $oldsortnum){
         //RUN SEPARATE QUERIES
         $sql_rename="UPDATE  `sourcedocs` SET sort1 = '999' WHERE sort1 =".$oldsortnum." AND category =  '".$category."'";
         $sql_reorder="UPDATE  `sourcedocs` SET sort1 = sort1 +1 WHERE sort1 >= ".$newsortnum." AND sort1 <= ".$oldsortnum." AND category =  '".$category."'";
         $sql_insert="UPDATE  `sourcedocs` SET sort1 =".$newsortnum." WHERE sort1 = '999' AND category =  '".$category."'";
    }
    //if new sort number is greater than old sortnum decrement all sortnums greater than new sortnum and decrement sortnums between 
    if ($newsortnum > $oldsortnum){
    //RUN SEPARATE QUERIES
         $sql_rename="UPDATE  `sourcedocs` SET sort1 = '999' WHERE sort1 =".$oldsortnum." AND category =  '".$category."'";
         $sql_reorder="UPDATE  `sourcedocs` SET sort1 = sort1 -1 WHERE sort1 <= ".$newsortnum." AND sort1 >= ".$oldsortnum." AND category =  '".$category."'";
         $sql_insert="UPDATE  `sourcedocs` SET sort1 =".$newsortnum." WHERE sort1 = '999' AND category =  '".$category."'";
    }
    ?>
```

Long story short - I stopped short of creating a PDO instance for the beginTransaction(); ...a little more messy, but it's working. I may switch to the PDO method but need to move on. Here's a link to the PDO info if you're having similar difficulties:

[PHP.net - PDO Construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)
[PHP.net - PDO beginTransaction();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php)